# jsp:include dosn't work.What's the reason?

Tags: jsp, servlets

In only one jsp page of my web application the command:

```
<jsp:include page="CercaCategorieServlet" flush="true"/>
```

don't call this Servet..Why?

What could be the reason?

Comment: try `page="/CercaCategorieServlet"`

Comment: What's the url mapping for this servlet? What's the location of the JSP?

Comment: This servlet is called inside a sidebar of web application ..In index.jsp it's works but if a call page1.jsp it's doesn't works

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions. To which URL is the servlet mapped? That information is in the web.xml (servlet-mapping element), or in the WebServlet annotation on the servlet.

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CercaCategorieServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CercaCategorieServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: Now where is the page1.jsp located relative to the root of your webapp? Is it directly under the root, or is it in some subdirectory?

Comment: \gfdeploy\E-Store\E-Store-war_war\page1.jsp  It's directly under the root

Comment: It should work, then. How do you determine that the servlet is not called? Are you sure this line of the JSP is executed and is not inside an `if (somethingFalse)`? Add traces just before the include and just after. Add traces to the servlet itself (in all its methods).

Comment: In the servlet I have wrote System.out.println("Hello") ..In index.jsp i read hello but not in page1.jsp..In page1.jsp there is another <jsp:include> to another servlet <jsp:include page="ContaRecensioniServlet" flush="true">
                <jsp:param name="id_articolo" value="<%=a.getId()%>" />
            </jsp:include>

Comment: You should avoid nesting jsp:includes